# How did the development in education impact the curiosity and creativity in German society pre and post WWI?

Tags: germany, world-war-one, science, art, spaceflight

I am currently researching this question; I know that the educational system focused more on science and math after the war which could have allowed for more curiosity and creativity in scientific fields, but if anyone has a deeper explanation of this I'd love to hear it. I am especially curious about Germany's space exploration, scientific/technological advancements, and even art/architecture.

Comment: @mathreadler: The fact that German education was "less hobbled" by religious and gender restrictions than those of other countries does not absolve it of the charge of being "hobbled." That is, "in the land of the blind, the one-eyed person is king/queen" (to be gender neutral).

Comment: Please document prior research..

Comment: What leads you to believe that science and math are connected to creativity and curiosity in scientific fields?  I am, to say the least, skeptical.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I don't remember what I wrote before I got censored, can you please tell me so I can make one answer?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yep I should know better than to try to do anything on here anyway. Obviously too many people who have full time work to make stuff up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, [German education](http://education.stateuniversity.com/pages/518/Germany-HISTORY-BACKGROUND.html) had been hobbled (by contemporary standards) by several issues. Among them were the fact that German schools had their origins in the 18th century as religious schools (with separate schools for Catholics, Protestants and Jews), and that women were not allowed to attend the Gymnasium (post middle school) until 1908, and the university until 1920.

These issues were (mostly) resolved by the 1920s, leading to broader (less religious) training for a wider segment of the population. Also, education was made compulsory until the age of 18, also allowing for a more varied curriculum, particularly for "optional" courses. Finally, teacher training was improved.

Also, the post (First World) war era was one of social, political, and artistic experimentation (e.g. more rights for women, the Weimar Republic and the Bauhaus art style) that found their way into the schools. Although these trends were interrupted by the Nazi regime, they most likely impacted their students decades later, post the *Second* World War.